# "Entity name must be unique in a persistence unit"

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I'm new to GlassFish server and I'm experiencing this problem. I first imported a template project (that uses JPA) into NetBeans, which was working fine. Then, since I wanted to modify the template, I created a copy of the project, closed the original one in NetBeans, undeployed the first project and then imported the new copied project into NetBeans. I changed the package name and the name of the persistence unit. However when I try to run the new project I get the error

```
Entity name must be unique in a persistence unit. Entity name [ToDoItem] is used for the entity classes [package1.ToDoItem] and [package2.ToDoItem]
```

How is this possible? The original project no longer exists in NetBeans, I explicitly undeployed it from GlassFish by using the asadmin undeploy command, and I even tried to remove and reinstall GlassFish, but nothing changes.

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myserver-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source/>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="create-script.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="drop-script.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="load-script.sql"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
</properties>
```

The only thing I changed is the name of the persistence unit.

Comment: What does your persistence.xml file look like? Perhaps you forgot to remove the classes under their old package name from that file when you copied it from the template project?

Comment: I added the persistence.xml, there is no mention of the old package name. But even if the package was the same, I don't understand the problem since the original application is no longer there!

Comment: Did you `Clean & Build` everything before redeploying?

Comment: Using a different name with @Entity(name = "...") helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and what worked for me was a clean project and removing the *osgi-cache* directory in the domain folder; it seems the built packages stay in the cache and cause naming conflicts.

Edit: a bit of clarification, I managed to get the same error on the clean install of *glassfish* because i had the old *.class* files in the project even though the source didn't exist and they ended up on the clean domain anyway.